# Docker compose up creating so many dangling/unncessary images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I run docker-compose up, it creates many unnecessary images. They are many in number and bigger in size.

I don't know why they are getting created.

**How can I stop it**? (as it consumes almost full memory of my computer).

FYR,

[image]

Comment: My guess is that those are intermediate images. Are you running Docker Desktop on Windows?

Comment: Yes, running docker desktop on windows.

Comment: Ok, so using Docker introduced a new builder for images called `BuildKit` https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/. This new builder does not export intermediate images as the legacy one used to. However, there is the following limitation: BuildKit only supports building Linux containers. Windows support is tracked in https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/616

Comment: Docker compose does not support the option of the legacy builder to remove the intermediate images as discussed here https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/9097. You can build the image using the `docker build --force-rm` with `-force-rm` removing the intermediate images as mentioned here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: You can verify that those are indeed intermediate and not dangling by running the `docker images -f dangling=true`. Should I write this as an answer so that it gets accepted?

Comment: Yes few of them are dangling images. Thanks. I will check other instructions as well....